# Linq on Extended Identiy2 AspUserRoles Table

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-identity

I extend the UserRole as below :

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    public ApplicationUserRole() : base() { }
    public int? ModelPk { get; set; }
    public MasterModelType MasterModelType { get; set; }
}
```

Now, i want to check, if a user has a specific role on a specific ModelPk. IE. Check if userA has roleB on project43.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure, but maybe try using lambda? maybe something like this:

```
    private void testMethod()
    {
        IdentityRole ident = new IdentityRole();
        var Role = ident.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.RoleId) == ModelPk);
    }
```

More detail might help.

Comment: Hi, Actually I am looking for something like this : `var Role = ident.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.RoleId) == RoleId && a.ModelPk  = 43 && a.UserId == userId);`  , I mean, check if the User(userID), has role(RoleID) on the project 43. But a.??? dont show the ModelPk.

Comment: it would be something like: var Role = ident.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.RoleId) == RoleId && ModelPk == 43 && a.UserId == userId).

Comment: But ModelPk is not defined. It should be a.ModelPK. But cant reach the modelPk in the table aspnetuserroles

Comment: yeah, its because ident.Users only contains RoleId and UserId. So you should be getting/checking ModelPk from elsewhere. Probably try something like :             IdentityRole ident = new IdentityRole();
            ApplicationUserRole appUserRole = new ApplicationUserRole();
            var Role = ident.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.RoleId) == RoleId && appUserRole.ModelPk == 43 && a.UserId == userId); ?